# Authenticating with the YouTube Upload widget

Tags: api, upload, youtube, widget, oauth-2.0

When using the YouTube API Version 2, to upload student videos from our website, we have the option of uploading using an upload html form, or using the "beta" YouTube Upload widget. The upload widget allows users to record directly from webcam to Youtube. (It is actually part of the YouTube API version 3 I guess.)

When we use the HTML form upload, we can authenticate the user server side via authsub or oauth2, and request a token which we add to the HTML form. However the Upload Widget seems to always require the user to login to YouTube via a little popup that the widget generates. It doesn't use the oauth2, or authsub.

Is there a way to use a token generated server side to avoid the user having to login using the little popup?